# Python store value into list and run a grep with if/else statement?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

Im creating a code in which I need to check the list ip addresses from npat variable which i need to create a loop, the code will run two things **1 is grep and 2 is lookup using whois** both of this task has 2 possible output and its either match or unmatch and result should be in the list.

Q's:

1. store the if/else statement result into a list that is the result from grep/whois?
2. What pattern should I use to match route: (spaces) from whois? so far my regex pattern for this work especially matching the address but I'm having issue matching the word "route:(spaces).

Some output:

```
npat list = ['6.120.0.0/18', '6.120.0.0/17', '13.44.61.0/24', '13.44.62.0/24']
```

Whois possible output:
1.

```
RADB:  %  No entries found for the selected source(s).
```

2. RADB:  route:      6.120.0.0/18
   descr:      name.com
   origin:     AS1111
   notify:     network@email.com
   source:     RADB

Here's the code:

```
import re, base64, os, sys

#SAMPLE STRING
teststr = """router#sh ip bgp        
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale, m multipath, b backup-path, x best-external
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
*> 6.120.0.0/18     2.2.2.11                          0 3111 2000 2485 43754 i
*> 6.120.0.0/17     2.2.2.11                          0 3111 2000 2485 43754 i
*> 13.44.61.0/24    2.2.2.11                          0 3111 4559 i
*> 13.44.62.0/24    2.2.2.11                          0 3111 4559 i"""
##print (teststr,"\n")

#SEARCH NETWORK ENTRY*Working)
npat = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})/\d+',teststr)
print ("List: \n",npat)

    for ips in npat:
    ipnet = ips.strip()
    print ("Processing ..... ", ipnet)
    fgen = "grep " +ipnet+ " /mnt/hgfs/IRR/fgen.txt"
    f2pat = re.findall(ipnet,fgen)
    print ("\nCommand: ",fgen)
    os.system(fgen)
    print ("\n NEW NPATH: ",f2pat)

    if ipnet in f2pat:
        flist = "Grep Found"
        print ("Result ", flist)
    else:
        flist = "Grep Not found"
        print ("Result: ",flist)

    f = os.popen('whois -h whois.radb.net ' + ipnet)
    who = f.read()
    radbpat = re.findall(ipnet,who)
    print ("\nRADB: ", who)

    radbpat = re.findall(r'(?<=route:      )(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})/\d+',who)
    print ("Radb :",radbpat)
    if ipnet in radbpat:
        rlist = "Found in RADB"
        print ("Result ", rlist)
    else:
        rlist = "Not found in RADB"
        print ("Result: ",rlist)

## OUTPUT
titles = ['RS-SET', 'GREP', 'RADB']
data = [titles] + list(zip(npat, flist, rlist))

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    line = '|'.join(str(x).ljust(15) for x in d)
    print(line)
    if i == 0:
        print('-' * len(line))
```

My target is to create a loop so I could check all the list of ip address from npat then the output shows the result from task 1 and 2??

I have created a table so my target output should be like this.

```
RS-SET         |Grep           |RADB           
--------------------------------------------

xx.xx.xx.0/yy  |not found      |Found
```

My Current output is like this:

```
RS-SET         |GREP           |RADB           
-----------------------------------------------
27.54.41.0/24  |G              |N              
223.253.0.0/20 |r              |o              
27.54.41.0/24  |e              |t              
27.54.42.0/24  |p              |               
27.54.43.0/24  |               |f
```

Grep and radb output has been vertically added... my flist and rlist has only 1 data.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a loop over a list of values? It sounds like you just need something like ```for ip in npat``` to create a for loop and do all of your logic

Comment: Hi @THeath, I have created a loop and modified the question.. my primarily issue is getting the list of result from grep and whois which should be stored in flist and rlist. Currently, Im getting a single string/value inputed in those 2 variable. so the output in table is vertically added

Comment: when you do `list(zip(npat, flist, rlist))` the `rlist` and `flist` variables are strings, not lists, so `zip` iterates over the characters in each. Maybe change your program to make `rlist` and `flist` Python `list()` types. For example, if `flist` were a list, you'd first have a line with `flist = []` and then in your `if/else` assign values as `flist.append("Grep Found")` or `flist.append("Grep Not Found")`

Comment: @THeath, Thanks.. its now a list but the thing is after looping Ive only got 1 value on rlist and flist which should be 4 result?? flist -> ['Grep Found'] 
 rlist -> ['Not in RADB']...... I used your code put an flist=[] before if/else and the append on the condition inside if/else....